# JMeter: include parameters from csv dataset in results

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I have a JDBC test suite that I run with JMeter, and I want to run that over many user accounts.

I'm doing that with a CSV dataset that includes all the accountIds I want to test, then I inject the accountId into my SQL queries to run the queries over all of the accounts I want to test (with ${ACCOUNTID}).

It's working great, the queries are actually done over all the accounts I want to test.

However, I would like to know the response time per account. Currently I'm not getting the accountId back in the result, so I can't filter my results by account. Is there a way to get that variable value to the JTL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either run JMeter as follows:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=ACCOUNTID -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Or add the next line to *user.properties* file to make the change permanent

```
sample_variables=ACCOUNTID
```

In both cases you will get an extra column in .jtl results file having ACCOUNTID variable value for each and every request.

More information:

- [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 1):

You can add variable name to Sampler name so it will aggregate requests per account id. Set Sampler as:

```
 My Sampler ${ACCOUNTID}
```